# Maze game text outputs

Tags: java

So I have this maze game and im trying to use a RNG to determine which message to print out when the user hits a wall, goes out of bounds, or reaches the end of the maze.  I have all these messages in my TextCard class but I want all the text cards regardless of what they are for to have a border around them, so I made another method called buildBorder but when I run my code it only outputs the message and not the border and I cant figure out why.

BUILDBORDER METHOD

```
public String buildBorder(String cardType){
        return ("**********************\n" + cardType + "\n" + "**********************");
```

WALLCARD METHOD

```
public String wallCard(){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        number = rnd.nextInt(100) + 1;
        if(number < 20 && number > 1){
            cardText = ("Going that way would lead to a painful face plant");
            return (cardText);
    }
    if(20 < number && number < 40){
        cardText = ("Some are destined for greatness, You are destined for a hard surface.  You cant go this way");
        return (cardText);
    }
    if(40 < number && number < 60){
        cardText = ("Are you lost? or do you just like running into walls?");
        return (cardText);
    }
    if(60 < number && number < 80){
        cardText = ("phasing is not your strong suit.  Find another way, this wall is as hard as your skull, take the hint.");
        return (cardText);
    }
    else{
        cardText = ("You spend longer than you should looking for the door handle, only to realize you ran into a wall.");
        return (cardText);
    }
  }
```

CONSTRUCTOR(part of it)

```
public TextCard(CardType cardType)
    {

       if(cardType == (CardType.WALL)){

           buildBorder(wallCard());

        }
```

GETCARD METHOD

```
public String getCard(){
        return this.cardText;
    }
```

METHOD CALL IN OTHER CLASS

```
else if((this.maze.isWall(x, y, "N")) == true){

                     System.out.println(new TextCard(TextCard.CardType.WALL).getCard());
```

also forgot to post this but these are my enums

```
public enum CardType{
        WALL, OUT, START, END
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `buildBorder(wallCard());` it returns a String.

You do not assign this String to anything - you don't print it, store it. So naturally, nothing happens.

`String temp = buildBorder(wallCard()); // NOW you can do whatever your heart desires`

Comment: I do print it in another class  System.out.println(new TextCard(TextCard.CardType.WALL).getCard());  and the string does print, it just doesnt print with the borders, itll just print "Going that way would lead to a painful face plant" without the asterisks

Comment: that's becuase you didn't print your buildBorder() method.

Comment: so I made my buildBorder method static and changed my method call to this      System.out.println(TextCard.buildBorder((new TextCard(TextCard.CardType.WALL).getCard())));     is that okay or is that bad design? it does work now

Comment: I would probably just change your getCard() method - or add a getCardWithBorder() method that returns: `return buildBorder(this.cardText);` so it's not so verbose